# Is there a way of converting a hierarchical list into a table in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a list like:

- Top Level 1

  - Sub Level 1

    - Sub Sub Level 1
    - Sub Sub Level 2
  - Sub Level 2

    - Sub Sub Level 3

(but bigger)

Is there a way I can convert the above into a table that looks like:

```
Top Level 1 | Sub Level 1 | Sub Sub Level 1
            |             | Sub Sub Level 2
            | Sub Level 2 | Sub Sub Level 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word doesn't have this functionality in particular, I'm afraid.

Comment: Rats! I guess they need to keep something for the next release!

Answer (score 3):

Word does not do this.

But I do have a solution using Excel that you can paste back into Word.

My solution uses a simple search and replace
and a native Text to Columns in a spreadsheet software.

### Generic solution

Step 1) Search and replace all the spaces/ tabs that make your hierarchy with the bullet. (In Word or in Excel or anywhere or plain text editor).
You'll end up with something like this

```
∙ item 1
∙∙ item 2
∙∙∙ item 3
```

Step 3) Paste into a spreadsheet and use the Text to Columns feature and split in on `your bullet character`. Done!

### My specific workflow using my apps of choice

Step 1) Copy paste the list from Workflowy as a plain text into Vscode. This results in a markdown style list.

```
- item 1
  - item 2
    - item 3
```

Step 2) Search and replace every `two spaces` and replace them with `-`

```
- item 1
-- item 2
--- item 3
```

Step 3) Copy paste into OpenOffice/ Excel. Use the Text to Columns feature and split in on `-`. Done! You get your table!

Answer (score 1):

**[BulletsToTable.com](https://bulletstotable.com/)**

I had the same problem - I make my notes as heirarchical lists in MS OneNote but sometimes want to show them as tables. This web app makes quick work of what you asked, just paste in your list!

Edit: **[Demo GIF here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7cx0.jpg)** to show it in action

Comment: It doesn't work for the example in the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill See the GIF I've added to show it working using the example in the question. Let me know if you're still having trouble - sometimes the indents can be imperfectly aligned depending on what was selected when copying, but these can be modified in the input box on this website directly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1. In Word, go to **New Number Format** under **Numbering**.
2. After the number, provide a distinct special
   character.
3. Do this for all hierarchical levels.
4. Copy and paste the entire content to Excel or Google Sheet along
   with the numbers and special characters. It will copy to a single
   column.
5. Write a formula using Find or Search to copy only the cells with the
   specific Special Character for a specific hierarchy.
6. Do this for all hierarchical levels.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you'd have to copy it back to Word after doing that.